# Não aparece todos meus class="posts" na página

Tags: html, css

Olá! Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo com html5, para aprender. Peguei um template pronto, utilizando boostrap. Estou com dificuldade em fazer aparecer em uma das minhas "paginas", todos os campos..

```
<ul class="posts">

<li class="post" id="postid1">
<a href="#" class="post_more"></a>         
      <div class="post_right_reveal">
        <h4>Academia Mendes</h4>
        <h4>(64)3615-2332</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="post_right_unreveal">
        <a href="#">Rua Bartolomou, N 23, Centro</a>                                                     
        <a href="#" class="post_readmore">Localização</a>
      </div> 

      <div class="post_left">
        <img src="images/item1-cardoso.png" alt="" title="" border="0" height="80" width="80"/>
      </div>
</li>

<li class="post" id="postid2">
<a href="#" class="post_more"></a>         
      <div class="post_right_reveal">
        <h4>Academia Mendes 2</h4>
        <h4>(64)3615-2322</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="post_right_unreveal">
        <a href="#">Rua Bartolomou, N 23, Centro</a>                                                     
        <a href="#" class="post_readmore">Localização</a>
      </div> 

      <div class="post_left">
        <img src="images/item1-cardoso.png" alt="" title="" border="0" height="80" width="80"/>
      </div>
</li>
</ul>

CSS:
ul.posts{ padding:0px; margin:0px; width:100%; display:block;}
ul.posts li.post{ width:100%; height:80px; margin:0 0 10px 0;    position:relative; display: block; }
```

Nesse caso eu coloquei apenas dois item (id="postid1" e id="postid2") aqui, para exemplo. Na minha pagina, ele só aparece 3 items. Eu não to sacando, o por que ele não quer aparecer os outros items em baixo.

[image: Imagem da minha pagina]

Comment: Podes [edit] a pergunta e explicar melhor o problema?

Comment: Quase todos meus posts <li class="post" id="postid1"> não querem aparecer na pagina, quando inseridos no html. Está aparecendo apenas três.

Comment: O que você está fazendo para repetir o `<li>` e gerar os demais `id`?

Comment: E essas classes "post_right_reveal", "post_right_unreveal", "post_left"... O que elas fazem? Verifique se não estão **escondendo** o conteúdo dos posts.

Comment: Por favor, para melhor orientarmos precisamos dos códigos utilizados: exemplo: javascript, jquery, css, html5 e se tiver outros cole. Pois podemos lhe dar diversos itens para pesquisar que pode ocultar os objetos, porém sem precisão.

Comment: Acho que esse tipo de template - que retorna esse resultados - deve ter arquivos php, onde estão as lógicas. Verifica se não é este o caso.